# How to union with a scalar value

Tags: entity-framework

In this pseudo-code, the last line won't work because the scalar value isn't IQueryable.

```
var scalarValue = 7;

var qry = (from t in db.Table
           where t.Filter == 5 //Arbitrary
           select t.ID);

var unioned = qry.Union(scalarValue);
```

It's straightforward in SQL:

```
select t.ID
from Table

union

select 7;
```

In my scenario I do need to select a valid Table.ID, so the workaround is:

```
var scalarValue = 7;

var qry = (from t in db.Table
           where t.Filter == 5 //Arbitrary
           select t.ID);

var scalarQry = (from t in db.Table
           where t.ID == scalarValue
           select t.ID);           

var unioned = qry.Union(scalarQry);
```

However, if there is a way to output "select 7;" for example, then that's what I'm after for this question.

Comment: tried `var unioned = qry.Union(new List<int>{scalarValue});` ?

Comment: @jbl that doesn't return an iqueryable, and that portion won't generate the SQL to run on the server.

Comment: I guess you did not try. You may have a look at my answer.

Comment: @jbl My mistake, I checked it when I got home - it works perfectly as hoped.

Comment: Note: use Concat() if you want to achieve union all.

Comment: Does anybody ever use `Enumerable.Repeat` - is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing

```
MyContext.MyClass.Select(t => t.Id).Union(new List<long>() { 42 }).ToList();
```

produces the following SQL query (`MyClass` is a `DbSet<MyClass>`) :

```
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [UnionAll1].[MyClassId] AS [C1]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[MyClassId] AS [MyClassId]
            FROM [dbo].[MyClasss] AS [Extent1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            cast(42 as bigint) AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]) AS [UnionAll1]
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```

The overload of Union which gets called is :

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Union<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source1, IEnumerable<TSource> source2)
```

in System.Linq.Queryable

I hope this will match your needs